# Simulator doesn't reflects the output

Tags: ios

I am working in iOS app dev.

I have more fields but cant able to get them in simulator...

[my actual xib here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzsFf.png)

here is the output,

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTqjK.png)

I removed all the things but still same output comes...

Comment: Why don't you update Xcode before?

Comment: Are you using autoLayout or autoresizing masks?

Comment: As I am new to this can't say about this exactly…Can you pls assis on how to know them.

Comment: - Get latest Xcode version 7.0 or 7.2 or 7.3.
- Do some simple example with autoresizing mask , search on google for tutorials.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using that old Xcode version?

Comment: my mac version 10.7.5, which supports this xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You need either use [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) or resize your interface builder file's content to your device's(or simulator's) screen size.